# Sorting indexs on an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which is like this:

```
array
  0 => 'Name1'
  1 => 'Name2'
  2 => 'Name1'
  3 => 'Name2'
  4 => 'Name3'
  5 => 'Name2'
  6 => 'Name1'
  7 => 'Name3'
```

After applying array_unique() for letting duplicated items go, my array goes like this:

```
  0 => 'Name1'
  1 => 'Name2'
  4 => 'Name3'
```

As you see, the array index is 0, 1, 4! I need this to be reset and go like a fresh array while you make it, like:

```
  0 => 'Name1'
  1 => 'Name2'
  2 => 'Name3'
```

How I could do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Call [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values). This will reset the keys.

Comment: I was going to say `sort()` but `array_values()` wil be lots faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well I try this, and work

```
$array = array( 
 0 => 'Name1',
  1 => 'Name2',
  2 => 'Name1',
  3 => 'Name2',
  4 => 'Name3',
  5 => 'Name2',
  6 => 'Name1',
  7 => 'Name3');


sort($array);
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    echo "nombre[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}
```

Result:

nombre[0] = Name1 nombre[1] = Name1 nombre[2] = Name1 nombre[3] = Name2 nombre[4] = Name2 nombre[5] = Name2 nombre[6] = Name3 nombre[7] = Name3